# How can strings be appended to environment variables in ktor application.yaml?

Tags: yaml, ktor

On https://ktor.io/docs/configuration-file.html#environment-variables merely a simple usage of an environment variable is demonstrated.
What I'd like to achieve is a concatenation of an env var and a constant string:

```yaml
kafka:
  streams:
    default:
      properties:
        state.dir: "$TMPDIR/it/streams/state"
```

However, when trying this or `"${TMPDIR}/it/streams/state"` the parser assumes that the whole string is a variable name...

Comment: That's impossible at the moment but you can make the concatenation in your code. Also, you can file a feature request (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=KTOR).